# How to remove space in function with python

Tags: python, function, concatenation

It may be simple, but I have only been doing this a week.

I am learning to define functions, so I was doing Columbus, Ohio tax as a test.

I keep getting a space between the dollar amount and the total no matter what I try. I was hoping someone had a solution. Again I am very new and just here to learn.

```
>>> def tax_ohio(subtotal):
        '''(number) -> number

Gives the total after Ohio tax given the
cost of an item.

>>> tax_ohio(100)
$107.5
>>> tax_ohio(50)
$53.75
'''
total = round(subtotal*1.075, 2)
return print('$',total)

>>> tax_ohio(100)
$ 107.5
```

Comment: A sidenote: I'd rather use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) for financial data.

Comment: A small point here - the results of your execution will always have 2 decimal places, so the answer will be `$107.50` and not `$107.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `+` instead of comma in the print function.`,` in the print function would print the default `sep` value ie, space.

```
print('$'+str(total))
```

Comment: >>> tax_ohio(100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#102>", line 1, in <module>
    tax_ohio(100)
  File "<pyshell#101>", line 13, in tax_ohio
    return print('$'+total)
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
>>>       

I get this error when I attempt that.

Comment: check my edit..it's `str(total)` . You could do like this `print('$',str(total), sep="")` also.

Comment: Thanks. Super useful to be able to convert numbers to strings.

Answer (score 3):

Use string formatting:

```
print('${}'.format(total))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I will be able to use that in the future as well!

Comment: It might worth considering `'${:.2f}'.format(total)`.

Comment: Good point @bereal, but considering there is already `total = round(subtotal*1.075, 2)` the number is already at the right precision.

Answer (score 1):

For avoiding the space, concatenate the variables with the `+` operator:

```
def tax_ohio(subtotal):
   total = round(subtotal*1.075, 2)
   print '$'+str(total)
```

The `,` automatically appends a space between the variables.

PS. Note that you have to manually cast the float to string, otherwise you would receive the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using print with multiple arguments, which automatically puts spaces in between. Instead use string concatenation. use `$+str(total)` instead.

The `str()` function converts the number to a string

and the `+` operator concatenates (joins) the two gives strings.